# Join models in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, model

in ASP.NET Visual Basic project with MVC5 and EntityFramework6  i have 2 model
one called User with columns(id,name,surname,companyid) and one called Company(id,name,address) in a SQL server Database.

How Can i join this two model in another model and create a controller that shows in a view the results of that join ?

Answer (score 1):

Here goes solution -

Model from EF -

[image]

Then you can have ViewModel as below -

```
public class UserMiniViewModel
{
    public string UName { get; set; }
    public string CName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action can be -

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<UserMiniViewModel> model = new List<UserMiniViewModel>();
        using (SampleEntities entities = new SampleEntities())
        {
            var results = from p in entities.Users
                          select new UserMiniViewModel()
                          {
                              UName = p.Name,
                              CName = p.Company.CompanyName
                          };
            model = results.ToList();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Index View is going to be -

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC.Controllers.UserMiniViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When you execute the code, your output is going to be -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How Can i join this two model in another model --> using `ViewModel`

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  public User UserInfo{get;set;}
}
```

since your UserInfo has a foreign key `CompanyId`, hope your User class might have a property called `Company` generated by EF. If not you can add it in your view model