# Join 3 tables in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to learn API development. This is my query:

```
select 
    companyusers.companyid, companies.companyname,
    companyusers.name, companyusers.id, compnayusers.designation, 
    personalInfo.otherinfo
from
    companyusers, companies, personalInfo
where 
    compnayusers.companyid = 2
    and compnayusers.id = personalInfo.userID
    and compnayusers.companyid = companies.companyid
    and compnayusers.IsRemote = 0
order by 
    compnayusers.name
```

I have to create an API that would parse the results of the above query in the JSON format.

My model classes:

```
[Table("companies")]
public class Companies
{
    public int compnayid { get; set; }
    public string companyname { get; set; }
}

[Table("companyusers")]
public class CompanyUsers
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string designation { get; set; }
    public int IsRemote { get; set; }
    public int companyid { get; set; }
}

[Table("personalInfo")]
public class PersonalInfo
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public string otherinfo { get; set; }
}
```

One view model class because I have to join the data of all these:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Companies companiesvm { get; set; }
    public PersonalInfo personalInfovm { get; set; }
    public CompanyUsers companyUsersvm { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` class:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ViewModel> viewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserContext userContext;
    
    public APIController(UserContext userContext)
    {
        this.userContext = userContext;
    }

    // GET api/<APIController>/5 
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
         // I am confused here 
        var result = from userlist in userContext.viewModels.  
    }
```

I know that now to connect with the database we will have to use `userContext` object. I don't know how to create a Linq expression for the same. I am stuck here.

And also, am I going the right way by creating the view model class and creating `DbSet` object of it? Please guide. Thanks.

I referenced these links too but don't know how to link all the tables with the `userContext` object:

http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Join-tables-and-return-result-into-view-usi

[Join models in asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458591/join-models-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I know the new way also. Its that I just posted the query as it was given to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't put the ViewModel into your DBContext. Make a DBSet for each table, so that you can access them seperate from each other if you need to:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Companies > Companies{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonalInfo> PersonalInfos{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyUsers> CompanyUsers{ get; set; }
}
```

For your API create Models that only hold the data your interested in. I would create specific Model foreach endpoint. My naming is provisional here (data according to your sql):

```
public class GetAPIModel
{
    public int CompanyID {get;set;}
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
    public string CompanyUserName {get;set;}
    public int CompanyUserID {get;set;}
    public string CompanyUserDesignation {get;set;}
    public string OtherInfo {get;set;}

}
```

Now you can execute your Query like this:

```
var data = (from p in userContext.CompanyUsers
                   join c in userContext.Companies
                   on p.companyid equals c.compnayid
                   join pInfo in userContext.PersonalInfos
                   on p.id equals pInfo.userID
                   where p.id == 1 and p.isRemote == 0
                   select new GetAPIModel
                   {
                       CompanyID = p.companyid,
                       CompanyName = c.companyname,
                       CompanyUserName = p.name,
                       CompanyUserID = p.id,
                       CompanyUserDesignation = p.designation,
                       OtherInfo = pInfo.otherinfo
                   })).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now data should hold your GetAPIModel with your informations needed to create your JSONResponse.

EDIT: Code adapted to fit the models specified by OP

Comment: How to add the compnayusers.IsRemote = 0 filter in the above LINQ?

Comment: wherd p.id == id && p.IsRemote == 0

Comment: var data returns a null even though I know I have data for that id in the database. I see data in the CompanyUsers, Companies, and personalInfo table. But var data is null.

Comment: Did you check the id in your GetMethod? Was is set correctly?

Comment: yes, it is taking the correct Id.

Comment: hmm I tried the code myself now, with a localDB with some sample data. It works for me. Maybe make sure that the id in the database is the same as the one you are handing over in the GET function

Comment: I even tried a simple expression, but it still gave me a count 0 . ```var data = (from mu in userContext.companyUsers  where mu.id == id select mu.name).ToList()```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256137/discussion-between-bugfish-and-anonymous).